# Validation rule on 3 picklist field which stores month(s) as values

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have 3 picklist field "StartMonth","MiddleMonth" and "Endmonth". which as values from january-december for all the 3 fields. i need validation rule to throw error if startmonth=january, middlemonth=september and endmonth should come after middle month and before startmonth. example ---> if endmonth comes inbetween startmonth and middle month it should throw error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created 3 new formula fields to get the numeric value for the month.Please find the code below for formula fields.

```
CASE( StartMonth__c, 
"January", 1, 
"February", 2, 
"March", 3, 
"April", 4, 
"May", 5, 
"June", 6, 
"July", 7, 
"August", 8, 
"September", 9, 
"October", 10, 
"November", 11, 
"December", 12, 
0)
```

I named these fields as StartMonthValue, MiddleMonthValue and EndMonthValue.

After that, I created validation rule as below to throw an error if End month is in between Start and Middle.

```
If(StartMonthValue__c < MiddleMonthValue__c , If( EndMonthValue__c >= StartMonthValue__c && 
EndMonthValue__c <= MiddleMonthValue__c , true,false) ,If( (EndMonthValue__c >= StartMonthValue__c && 
EndMonthValue__c >= MiddleMonthValue__c) || (EndMonthValue__c <= StartMonthValue__c && 
EndMonthValue__c <= MiddleMonthValue__c) , true,false))
```

As your fields as Picklist, we cannot use Date methods to get month value.

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! Get the `month` component of the `Date` and use the `operator` to find where the end month lies

```
    If((VALUE(TEXT(MONTH(Endmonth__c))) > VALUE(TEXT(MONTH(startMonth__c)))) && 
(VALUE(TEXT(MONTH(Endmonth__c))) < VALUE(TEXT(MONTH(MiddleMonth__c)))),  true,false)
```

[image]